# Global variable pointer to class of user-defined type

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, global

I have problem. I want to have one global pointer containing adress of my class. And this pointer should be visible for all other parts of program. This is my source code of objects:

```
//FILEname:LP_poGlobalObject.cpp    

#include "LP_poGlobalObject.h"  //this is header file to be included by all other files
#include "LP_PSI_Object.h"      //include oPsiTestStrategy class

    oPsiTestStrategy* poGlobalObject = NULL;  
                     //create new pointer supposed to be global
```

this is header file for this global variable pointer

```
//FILEname:LP_poGlobalObject.h

#if !defined LP_PSI_OBJECT_GLOBAL_H
#define LP_PSI_OBJECT_GLOBAL_H

    extern oPsiTestStrategy* poGlobalObject; //error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'

#endif
```

At the marked line I get a compiler error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
```

and this is class oPsiTestStrategy used above

```
//FILEname:LP_PSI_Object.h

#if !defined LP_PSI_OBJECT_H 
#define LP_PSI_OBJECT_H

class oPsiTestStrategy
        {
           public:
                oPsiTestStrategy();
                virtual ~oPsiTestStrategy();
                virtual Word    zPsiGetSourceId_Testing_O(EvtId xEvtPktId);
                virtual Dword   zPsiGetData_Testing_O(EvtId, void*);
                virtual Dword   zPsiGetDataLen_Testing_O( EvtId );
                virtual void    vPsiExitEvent_Testing_O( EvtId );
                virtual void    vPsiCancelEvent_Testing_O( EvtId );
                virtual void    vPsiSetUserStatus_Testing_O( EvtId , Word );
        }; 
#endif
// methods are virtual because I want to test this and replace it with mock objects - GTest, UnitTesting. 
//Is this causing my problem?
```

Desired result of this should be something like this:

```
#include "LP_poGlobalObject.h"

int main()
{
poGlobalObject->vPsiCancelEvent_Testing_O((EvtId)5);
}
```

Thanks people, have a nice day.. :-)

Comment: You are missing an include file or a forward declaration for the typename `oPsiTestStrategy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oPsiTestStrategy` type is not know at the point where you use it in `LP_poGlobalObject.h`. You have to reorder the includes:

```
#include "LP_PSI_Object.h"      //include oPsiTestStrategy class
#include "LP_poGlobalObject.h"  //this is header file to be included by all other files
```

You could also include `LP_PSI_Object.h` in `LP_poGlobalObject.h` or make a forward declaration for `oPsiTestStrategy` before defining an external object of that type.

Answer (score 1):

In your header file add - before definition of global variable...

```
class oPsiTestStrategy;
```

So the compiler knows what a oPsiTestStrategy is...

Answer (score 1):

`oPsiTestStrategy` has to be defined or forward declared when

```
extern oPsiTestStrategy* poGlobalObject;
```

is declared, otherwise it is not known to the compiler.

Add include directive

```
#include "LP_poGlobalObject.h"
#include "LP_PSI_Object.h"
```

or forward declaration for `oPsiTestStrategy` type:

```
class oPsiTestStrategy;
```